# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10101010101010101010101010101010"

Tags: java, binary, integer

The binary string is **"10101010101010101010101010101010"**, 32 bits

Got this exception when i try

```
Integer.parseInt("10101010101010101010101010101010", 2);
```

But the same string(add "0b" prefix)

```
System.out.print(0b10101010101010101010101010101010);
```

return -1431655766.

Is this a valid binary string?

Answer (score 2):

Integer.parseInt() is the wrong method as it only accepts signed numbers.

With Java8, use:

```
Integer.parseUnsignedInt("10101010101010101010101010101010", 2);
```

Before Java8, use:

```
(int) Long.parseLong("10101010101010101010101010101010", 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The value you wanted to convert goes beyond the `int` type size, Use`BigInteger`:

```
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger("10101010101010101010101010101010",2);
```

Comment: Or...you know...`long`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder of course, but he may expect longer values afterwards

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.parseInt("10101010101010101010101010101010", 2);
```

Note that this would be 2863311530, which would cause an overflow, as it is above Integer.MAX_VALUE.

```
System.out.print(0b10101010101010101010101010101010);
```

This however uses the internal representation of an integer, which is two-complement form. Thats why it is negative. The `Integer.parseInt()` however treats it as an unsigned binary number, which causes the Exception.

It is important to understand the different bit representations.

Edit: If you want your input to be interpreted as two-complement, use this:

```
Integer.parseUnsignedInt("10101010101010101010101010101010", 2);
```

Comment: Thx, but why `Integer.parseInt()` doesn't treat it as two-complement form?

Comment: @鸡蛋花树 Because it is just defined like that, There is `Integer.parseUnsignedInt(..)` for what you want to do.